# How to get the closed form solution from DSolve[]?

Tags: evaluation

Hi I've noticed something rather annoying which is when I try to use this function DSolve to check the answers to my homework problems it will simply not show a solution due to lazy evaluation.

E.g.:

```
DE = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]
BC1 = u[0, t] == 0
BC2 = u[1, t] == 0
IC1 = u[x, 0] == 0
sol = DSolve[{DE, BC1, BC2,  IC1}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Outputs:
[image]

While this maybe technically correct (from a programming perspective) it isn't any use to me because it essentially just output the original function call. How do I get an actually useful (i.e. closed form) answer from this function?

Comment: There may be several  equivalent closed-form expressions for the result of `DSolve`.

Comment: @user64494 In that case I'd be looking for the simplest one. Or any closed form solution at all lol. Anything is better than echoing my function call back to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is having hard time with initial conditions. One workaround is to solve it without the IC, then you'll see the solution has $u(x,0)$ in it. You can then just replace that with zero, since that is what you have for IC.

```
DE = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]
BC1 = u[0, t] == 0
BC2 = u[1, t] == 0
IC1 = u[x, 0] == 0 (*do not use in the DSolve*)
sol = DSolve[{DE, BC1, BC2}, u[x, t], {x, t}] /. K[1] -> n
```

[image]

```
sol /. u[x, 0] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above seems to agree with Maple's solution

```
DE := diff(u(x,t),t$2) =diff(u(x,t),x$2);
BC1 := u(0, t) = 0;
BC2 := u(1, t) = 0;
IC1 := u(x, 0) = 0;
pdsolve([DE,BC1,BC2,IC1])
```

[image]

Where the $c_{1_{n}}$ above goes with that integral in Mathematica's solution. But may be this need more verification. This is only way I found to make it give a solution.

Btw, you need to keep arguments consistent, You used $u(x,t)$ in one place and used $u(t,x)$ in other places. Also better to keep same order for `x,t` in final argument in DSolve in same order they show up inside $u$.

Comment: Thanks, so in general you can't really rely on Mathematica to "just solve" these problems? Do they need to be sufficiently simple or something?

Comment: @profPlum DSolve is very good in solving ode's and pde's but as always, there are limitations and things it still can't solve. There is a page [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/pde_in_cas.htm) that lists solving pde's using Mathematica you can check. Solving pde's is much harder than ode's as you know, so the state of art in this area is still not advanced as with odes'.

Comment: This series is not a closed-form expression, but an analytical expression (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for the definitions).